# how to make SSH connection in apache

Tags: php, apache, ansible, centos

I trying to build a web app to manage my severs using ansible

now I using Centos 7, PHP 7.4,Laravel 8 and apache to build this app and I'm already install https://packagist.org/packages/asm/php-ansible composer package for using ansible inside of my project.

here is my code:

```
$ansible = new Asm\Ansible\Ansible(
        '/var/www/xxx/storage/ansible',
        '',
        ''
    );

$ansible->playbook()->play($myplaybookPath)->inventoryFile($myInventoryPath)->execute(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (Process::ERR === $type) {
            echo 'ERR > '.$buffer ."<br/>";
        } else {
            echo 'OUT > '.$buffer."<br/>";
        }
    });
```

Here is the output :

```
OUT > PLAY [install nano] ************************************************************
OUT > TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
OUT > fatal: [xx.xx.14.139]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
OUT > PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
OUT > xx.xx.14.139 : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=1 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
OUT >
```

the username and password in the inventory file is correct and I test it many times also I try with new server with a very simple password.

I google this error `host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)."` and I found out its about the authorized_keys for the user that run the ssh

I change the permission and mod of the .ssh folder for my apache user in `/var/user/share/httpd/.ssh`

buy this error still remain and I don't know how to fix this.

thanks for help

### update

it's not about my web server Configuration and everything about apache and PHP is ok.

I run my the playbook directly from terminal using ansible-playbook:

`ansible-playbook /var/www/xxx/storage/ansible/playbooks/install_nano -i /var/www/xxx/storage/ansible/inventories/testInventory -vvv`

I got the same error and I guess it's about the Auth information in InventoryFile

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.25
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /var/www/xxx/storage/ansible/inventories/testInventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /var/www/xxx/storage/ansible/inventories/testInventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /var/www/xxx/storage/ansible/inventories/testInventory inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'actionable', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'counter_enabled', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'debug', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'full_skip', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'json', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'null', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'selective', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'skippy', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'stderr', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'unixy', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'yaml', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: install nano ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in /var/www/xxx/storage/ansible/playbooks/install nano

PLAY [install nano] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /var/www/xxx/storage/ansible/playbooks/install nano:2
<xx.xx.14.139> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<xx.xx.14.139> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a7f10d151a xx.xx.14.139 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~root && sleep 0'"'"''
<xx.xx.14.139> (255, '', 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
fatal: [xx.xx.14.139]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
xx.xx.14.139               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Here is the inventory file content

```
[linux]

xx.xx.14.139

[linux:vars]

ansible_user=root
ansible_password=testPassword
```

also, I try ansible_ssh_user / password but it's not working!

Comment: Is this the correct home directory for the apache user?
/var/user/share/httpd

Comment: yes when I make some changes on permissions I got error from this path

Comment: Are you sure you did not set a password in ansible.cfg which would override the one you set in your inventory? With the information you gave, the only possibility to get such an error message is that your credentials are invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

I enabled verbose mode in ssh connection and I notice that the outcoming SSH request didn't support Password Authentication.

There are 2 SSH config files /etc/ssh/sshd.conf for the incoming requests and /etc/ssh/ssh.cong for outcoming so I fix the issue from out coming request config file and enable the password authentication.

after that, I set permissions for my apache ssh files like keys and known hosts files.

after that, I create a command in laravel so I can run my ansible playbooks using the root user and Crond.